# Kotlin data class: How to cast property value to its actual property type using Kotlin reflection?

Tags: kotlin, dynamic, reflection, casting

How can I convert the value of `kProperty1.get(myClassInstance!!)` to its actual type? Currently, the type is `Any?` and I need to pass it to a function that requires a specific type. I obtain `kProperty1` using `MyClass::class.declaredMemberProperties.firstOrNull { it.name == target }` and `myClassInstance` is an instance of `MyClass`.

My code is like:

```
 val kProperty1 = MyClass::class.declaredMemberProperties.firstOrNull { it.name == propName }
     
            val valueFirst = myClassInstance1?.let { kProperty1.get(it) }
            val valueSecond = myClassInstance2?.let { kProperty1.get(it) }
            compareValues(valueFirst, valueSecond)
```

I can't call compareValues due to this error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but Comparable<*> was expected
```

I need to compare two instances of MyClass by one property which name and type I don't know at compile time.

For example this property can be Long or String or LocalDate

Comment: Could you please show the code that doesn't work? If the function requires a specific type, then why do you need to cast this value to the declared type of the property? You should just need to cast the value to whatever the function expects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the only thing you know about the property is that the type is a Comparable, cast the property type to `Comparable<*>`. The `compareValues` function will work even without knowing what the `T` of `Comparable` is, as long as the two arguments are actually the same type of Comparable, which we know is true since they came from the same KProperty.

```
val kProperty1 = MyClass::class.declaredMemberProperties
    .firstOrNull { it.name == target } as KProperty1<MyClass, Comparable<*>>?
requireNotNull(kProperty1) { "Property $target not found" }
val value1 = myClassInstance1?.let { kProperty1.get(it) }
val value2 = myClassInstance2?.let { kProperty1.get(it) }
val result = compareValues(value1, value2)
```

or

```
val kProperty1 = MyClass::class.declaredMemberProperties
    .firstOrNull { it.name == target } as KProperty1<MyClass, Comparable<*>>?
requireNotNull(kProperty1) { "Property $target not found" }
val value1 = myClassInstance1?.let(kProperty1::get)
val value2 = myClassInstance2?.let(kProperty1::get)
val result = compareValues(value1, value2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the type of the property is not MyClass. This property is part of the class and its type is something like String, or Long. I need this property type. Please see my updated question.